# String.format not displaying full message

Tags: java

```
String Quote = String.format(
    "This triangle has an perimeter of %.2f", TP ," and an area of %.2f",TA
);
System.out.printf(Qoute);
```

the following code prints out "

> This triangle has an perimeter of 17.94

" and leaves out the "," and an area of %.2f",TA". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Consult [the Javadoc for `Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) (linked from [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))) to see examples of correct usage.

Comment: Your answer is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29

Answer (score 6):

You given the wrong format. The later params will considered as inputs to the first param. Try

```
String quote = String.format(
    "This triangle has an perimeter of %.2f  and an area of %.2f", 
    TP ,TA
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should pass all the parameters at the end

## Example:

instead doing this:

```
String Quote = String.format(
    "This triangle has an perimeter of %.2f", TP ," and an area of %.2f",TA
);
```

do...

```
String Quote = String.format("This triangle has an perimeter of %.2f and an area of %.2f", TP, TA);
System.out.printf(Quote);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

> `public static String format(String format,
>               Object... args)`
>
> Parameters:
>       format - A format string
>       args - Arguments referenced by the format specifiers in the format string. If there are more arguments than format specifiers, **the extra arguments are ignored**.

---

So to your question:

> " and leaves out the "," and an area of %.2f",TA". What am I doing wrong?

Since the extra arguments are ignored after the 1st arg, it *leaves out the "," and an area of %.2f",TA"*